# The Page Rest its CSS When Dropdown is Updated

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have this page. The drop-down lists and the radio buttons are written in ASPX. The drop-down look, on the other hand, is controlled by a CSS file.

[image]

The problem I am having is that when the first drop-down is updated, the page resets its CSS all of a sudden. That happens only to the ASPX code (you notice that the next button stays normal).

[image]

I compared the source of the two pages and it is identical. For some reason, the ASPX part is reset, but the rest of the page works normal.

Does anyone knows what could cause such problem?

This is the ASPX code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="online_giving.aspx.cs" EnableEventValidation="false" Inherits="mpp.online_giving" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title>Online Giving</title>
  </head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" class="mpp_page_OnlineGiving">
  <div>
    <table id="PageTitle" class="formTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
      <tr>
        <td class="mpp_formTitle">Step 1 of 3: Give Online</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" runat="server" DisplayAfter="100">
      <ProgressTemplate>
        <div id="progressDiv">
          <br /><br />
          <center>
            <img src="spinner6.gif" width="16" height="16" alt="Loading..." />                    
            <label>Loading...</label>
          </center>
        </div>
      </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate> 

        <table ID="PageGivingControls" class="formTable" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
          <tr id="mpp_online_giving_tr_campus" runat="server">
            <td class="mpp_formLabel"><asp:Literal ID="litCampusLabel" runat="server"></asp:Literal>:</td>
            <td class="mpp_formControl">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCampus" runat="server"
                CssClass="dropdowns" AutoPostBack="true"
                onselectedindexchanged="ddlCampus_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="mpp_online_giving_tr_designation">
            <td class="mpp_formLabel">Designation:</td>
            <td class="mpp_formControl">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPurpose" runat="server" 
                                CssClass="dropdowns" AutoPostBack="true" 
                                onselectedindexchanged="ddlPurpose_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="mpp_online_giving_tr_amount">
            <td class="mpp_formLabel">Amount:</td>
            <td class="mpp_formControl">
              <asp:TextBox ID="txtAmount" runat="server" CssClass="textboxes" MaxLength="8" ></asp:TextBox>
              <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCurrency" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <asp:Panel ID="pnlRecurringGiving" runat="server">
            <tr id="mpp_online_giving_tr_onetime" runat="server">
              <td class="mpp_formLabel">Frequency:</td>
              <td class="mpp_formControl">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioOnetime" runat="server" Text="One-time Gift" 
                                 GroupName="frequency" Checked="true" />
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="mpp_online_giving_tr_weekly" runat="server">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="mpp_formControl">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioWeekly" runat="server" Text="Weekly, " 
                                 GroupName="frequency" />
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFrequency" runat="server">
                  <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Every"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Every Other"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGivingDays" runat="server" CssClass="dropdowns" >
                  <asp:ListItem Value="1" Text="Sunday"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="2" Text="Monday"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="3" Text="Tuesday"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="4" Text="Wednesday"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="5" Text="Thursday"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="6" Text="Friday"></asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="7" Text="Saturday"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList> until
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtWeeklyExpiration" runat="server" Text="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>

              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="mpp_online_giving_tr_monthly" runat="server">
              <td>&nbsp;</td>
              <td class="mpp_formControl">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="radioMonthly" runat="server" Text="Monthly, on the" GroupName="frequency" />&nbsp;

                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlMonthDays" runat="server" CssClass="dropdowns" >
                  <asp:ListItem Value="1">1st</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="5">5th</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="10">10th</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="15">15th</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="20">20th</asp:ListItem>
                  <asp:ListItem Value="25">25th</asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>&nbsp;of Every Month until
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtMonthlyExpiration" runat="server" Text="mm/dd/yyyy"></asp:TextBox>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                  toggleFrequency();
                </script>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </asp:Panel>
        </table>


      </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel> 


    <div>
      <asp:Literal ID="litGiftError" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
    </div>

    <div id="mpp_ShareLinkContainer">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnShowLink" runat="server" Text="Share Link" CssClass="mpp_navLink"
                      onclick="btnShowLink_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtShareLink" CssClass="mpp_shareLink" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>  
      <div class="mpp_formControl">
        <asp:Literal ID="Literal1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>&nbsp;
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mpp_inline_left">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewCart" runat="server" CssClass="mpp_navLink" 
                      onclick="btnViewCart_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    <div class="mpp_inline_right">
      <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddGift" runat="server" Text="Next" 
                      CssClass="mpp_navLink" onclick="btnAddGift_Click" />      
    </div>


    <div class="mpp_formControl">
      <asp:Literal ID="litShareLinkHelp" runat="server"></asp:Literal>&nbsp;
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing stuff client side. Are you familiar with your browser's developer tools? Viewing the source doesn't give you how your source looks after it has been manipulating it. You need to view it in your developer tools to get a better understanding.

Comment: Could you help me how to solve this problem?

Comment: What Chris said. How does the dropdown get updated? Also, are you using `<br>` for layout? and `<center>`, really?

Comment: Hi @MrLister. The code is written by someone else and I just want to fix this problem. The data is retrieved from a database.